# Node.js: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu

### Synopsis

I do not know how to find the problem. Please assist me in debugging.
I updated from nodev18 to nodev20 and could no longer execute my jest-tests, jest --version was working but jest test was failing.
So I investigated further, and it seems like a issue with node and *some* unknown code execution that causes the exit because I even cannot run `npm start` on a new project.

### Relevant versions

Kubuntu 23.10 mantic on 6.7.9-060709-generic Kernel
node v20.11.1 (from snap store)
npm 10.2.4
Angular CLI: 17.2.3

### Reproduction

How to reproduce (on my system)
clean angular installation:

```
$ ng new foo
*snip*
✔ Packages installed successfully.
$ cd foo
$ npm start

> foo@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

⠧ Building...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

### further logs & information

I already tried node from different repos: snap, source, debian in version 20 and 21.
Only when I switch back to v18 `npm start`/`npm test` works.
It does not fail on the building, I think. The command `npm run build` does work without any issue.

```
$ cat /home/frozen_byte/.npm/_logs/2024-03-13T16_47_20_594Z-debug-0.log 
0 verbose cli /snap/node/8286/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@10.5.0
2 info using node@v20.11.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/frozen_byte/IdeaProjects/foo/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/frozen_byte/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/snap/node/8286/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 4ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 4ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm start
22 verbose argv "start"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/frozen_byte/.npm/_logs/2024-03-13T16_47_20_594Z-
26 verbose logfile /home/frozen_byte/.npm/_logs/2024-03-13T16_47_20_594Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 4ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 15ms
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
32 silly logfile done cleaning log files
33 timing command:run-script Completed in 1177ms
34 timing command:start Completed in 1180ms
35 verbose exit 132
36 timing npm Completed in 1210ms
37 verbose code 132
```

```
$ sudo dmesg -w
*snip*
[ 6998.095159] traps: ng serve[25856] trap invalid opcode ip:57a7ac88ab84 sp:7fce865f9dc8 error:0 in node[57a7ab350000+1bc4000]
```